# java.io.IOException: Attempt to allocate a texture to big for the current hardware

Tags: java, textures, lwjgl, ioexception

I'm writing a game in Java using LWJGL and the slick.util libraries. Currently I'm having a problem using a spritesheet. Some colleagues of mine told me that the sprites would probably look better if they were smaller. My spritesheet was a single row of 8 sprites, each sprite being 128x64. This would make the whole spritesheet 1028x64. I used a tool online to reshape the sheet to 512x32, but this produced my error.

```
java.io.IOException: Attempt to allocate a texture to big for the current hardware
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:320)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:254)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:200)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader.getTexture(TextureLoader.java:64)
    at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader.getTexture(TextureLoader.java:24)
    at com.hasherr.dinopizzaattack.graphics.TextureHandler.getTexture(TextureHandler.java:26)
    at com.hasherr.dinopizzaattack.entity.Player.getSprite(Player.java:105)
    at com.hasherr.dinopizzaattack.entity.Player.draw(Player.java:129)
    at com.hasherr.dinopizzaattack.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:36)
    at com.hasherr.dinopizzaattack.screens.ScreenManager.render(ScreenManager.java:49)
    at com.hasherr.dinopizzaattack.core.Game.play(Game.java:71)
    at com.hasherr.dinopizzaattack.core.Game.main(Game.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

This is strange for a variety of reasons. For one, this spritesheet is *smaller* than the first one I was using, so I'm not sure why it would be telling me that the texture itself is too large. Secondly, according to Cody S's answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569654/java-io-ioexception-difficulty-when-adding-player-texture-into-screen), you can find your graphics card's maximum texture size after printing this out in my TextureHandler class, the class which loads textures using the slick-util class, I found that my maximum is 8192.

```
public class TextureHandler
{

    // Used to deliver a texture to entities for quad-rendering.
    public static Texture getTexture(String name, String ext)
    {
        System.out.println(GL11.glGetInteger(GL11.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE));
        Texture texture = null;
        try
        {
            texture = TextureLoader.getTexture(ext.toUpperCase(),
                    ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream( "res/sprites/" + name + "." + ext.toLowerCase()));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0); // Exit the game if the texture isn't loaded properly.
        }

        return texture;
    }
}
```

This is the code that loads my textures.

Currently I've tried to get information regarding my graphics card and the maximum texture size (I have an Intel HD Graphics Family card), I've tried resizing the image back to it's inital size, and talked to some people about the problem. Nothing seems to be working.
So why is my machine telling me that these sprites are too large, when sprites even bigger were working fine?

Comment: Your image file might be corrupted because you used an online converter. Try to use a different texture to find out if the texture is at fault or some other change you have since made.

Comment: @Njol Will do; I'll keep you updated.

Comment: @Njol This did not work. I received the same error.

Comment: I suggest to debug the application if you know how to do that - in Eclipse the debug button is just next to the run button. Eclipse should automatically halt the JVM when the exception is encountered and put you into the debug perspective where you can inspect all variables at the time of the exception to find out what exactly is happening.

Comment: @Njol I'm currently on IntelliJ, and yes I do know how to use the debugger. I'll look around.